# To print values in diferent line in mail body shell script

Tags: shell-script, cat, mailx

Below is the code to print contents of files present in the directory 
File contents are :

```
apple 
banana 
grapes 
mango
```

names=()

```
FILES=/path_to_dir/*
for f in $FILES
do
   names+=($f)
done
result="$(cat ${names[@]})"
echo "$result"

echo "The  names are "$result"" | mailx -s "names are " abc@gmail.com
```

for this I am getting below output for result variable

```
apple 
banana 
grapes 
mango
```

However when I print "$result" in email I got below output in email's text:

```
apple banana grapes mango
```

I want to send names in email with multiline like this :

```
apple 
banana 
grapes 
mango
```

How to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `echo -e "The names are:\n" "$result"`

The `-e` option allows the newline sign `\n` interpretation; variable is then expanded correctly, by having its own double quotes.